# PySpark how to get the partition name on query results?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I would like to retrieve the partition name on query results.

So if I have a partition like:

```
dataset/foo/
        ├─ key=value1
        ├─ key=value2
        └─ key=value3
```

I can do this query

```
results = session.read.parquet('dataset/foo/key=value[12]') \
                      .select(['BAR']) \
                      .where('BAZ < 10')
```

Once I do this how to know the partition origin for each results ?

Indeed I can get only values form the `BAR` column.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `key` column in your select statement!

```
#read foo directory as it is partiitoned so we can filter on the key
results = session.read.parquet('foo/') \
                      .select(['BAR','key']) \
                      .filter((col("key") == "value1") & (col("BAZ") < '10'))
```

---

In case if you want to add origin **filename** to all records then use `input_file_name()`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
results = session.read.parquet('foo/') \
                      .select(['BAR','key'])\
                      .withColumn("input_file", input_file_name()) \
                      .filter((col("key") == "value1") & (col("BAZ") < '10'))
```

Comment: if I include the `key` column I got an error: `cannot resolve «key» given input columns: [BAR, BAZ]`

Comment: @bioinfornatics, Please check the EDITED answer!

Comment: Thanks @shu . little question in such case spark read only necessary parquet files or it scan all files from the given root path ?

Comment: @bioinfornatics, spark will only read the directory `value[12]` files as this is partitioned directory, if not partitioned then all files will be read!

Comment: Note on my side statement `(col("key") == "value[12]")` return an empty dataframe . I replaced it with `filter((col('key') >= 'value1') & (col('key') <= 'value2'))`

Comment: I found that `rlike` expression  allow to use `"value[12]"`